# What is a more optimal algorithm for this problem?

Tags: python, algorithm, performance, data-structures, time-complexity

Suppose you have an array `A` of `N` integers. In one round, you make changes as follows (based on the array snapshot at the beginning of the round):

- -= 1 if greater than both adjacent (on both sides)
- += 1 if less than both adjacent (on both sides)

The one on the edges/ends never change, and you keep going while a change was made the previous round.

A simple algorithm looks like:

```
    while True:
        prior = A
        cur = A[:]
        for i in range(1, len(cur) - 1):
            if prior[i - 1] > prior[i] and prior[i + 1] > prior[i]:
                cur[i] += 1
            elif prior[i - 1] < prior[i] and prior[i + 1] < prior[i]:
                cur[i] -= 1
        if cur == prior:
            break
        A = cur
    return A
```

This was for a coding assessment I recently took. Here's a couple examples:

```
Input: [1, 6, 3, 4, 3, 5]
Returns: [1, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5]

Input: [100, 50, 40, 30]
Returns: [100, 50, 40, 30]
```

**Explanation for 1st case:**

`1` and `5` at the ends never change since they don't have both neighbours. This will also be true for any testcase. Next state would be as below,

```
[ 1, 5, 4, 3, 4, 5]
```

- arr[2] = 5 since `1 < 6 > 3`, `6` gets reduced by 1 making it `5`
- arr[3] = 4 since `6 > 3 < 4`, `3` gets increased by 1 making it `4`.
- arr[4] = 3 since `3 < 4 > 3`, `4` gets reduced by 1 making it `3`.
- arr[5] = 4 since `4 > 3 < 5`, `3`, gets increased by 1 making it `4`.

  ```
  [ 1, 5, 4, 3, 4, 5] becomes [1, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5] in a similar fashion as above and stops here since no further operations can be performed.
  ```

**Explanation for 2nd case:**

No action is taken on the array since none of the non-border elements have neighbours where both are either smaller or greater.

Comment: should be the output for first example would be `[1, 5, 4, 4, 4, 5]`

Comment: @sahasrara62 Of course no. In the next round `1, 5, 4` changes to `1, 4, 4`,

Comment: If you have working code that you want to optimize, consider posting in [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/tour) instead.

Comment: What is the maximum length of the array possible?

Comment: there's no such thing as "most optimal" because by definition optimal is the best of all possible solutions. You cannot have a "least optimal" solution because it wouldn't be optimal, as a consequence there cannot be a most optimal solution.

Comment: Keeping the previous, current, and next values in variables would probably be more efficient than indexed array values. You can left shift the values and import the next from the array on each iteration.

Comment: I'm looking for a better algorithm, not to optimize the current code. This algorithm works.